# Is it possible to create a binary analysis software which would sort out all possible vulnerabilities and bugs in other software?

Tags: security, binary, analysis

I find myself often questioning myself whether it is possible to design a software which would load up another software and try to emulate all possible outcomes from it and figure out bugs and vulnerabilities on the software being analyzed.

Theoretically, it could load any piece of software, have an internal representation of the underlying system (CPU registers, memory, etc) like a Virtual Machine software, and by means of analyzing, it would start fetching the instructions, emulating them, which would go linearly until it finds a conditional jump.

To make it simple to understand, when it finds a conditional jump, it would take a snapshot of the current representational state of the system and follow that conditional jump, it would keep evaluating the instructions and at some point would restore that snapshot and do not follow the conditional jump, going past over it and evaluating the next instructions, and so on.

Such software would be smart enough to emulate user supplied input.

To make things clearer lets imagine we are analyzing the following (pseudo?) C code:

```
char* gets(char *s)
{
  int i = 0;
  while( (s[i] = _getche()) != VK_RETURN ) i++;
  s[i] = NULL;
  return s;
}

void main() {
  char buf[8];
  char is_admin = FALSE;

  do {
    gets( buf );

    if( _strcmp(buf, "s3cr3t!") == 0 )
      is_admin = TRUE;
    else
    {
      if( is_admin )
        super_user.exec( buf );
      else
        unprivileged_user.exec( buf );
    }

  } while( _strcmp(buf, "exit") != 0 );
}
```

It just keeps polling for user commands and executes them until the user input is "exit". if the user inputs a password "s3cr3t!" them it will execute the following commands as a super user, otherwise it will just impersonate an unprivileged user.

Moving on, we could ask our analysis software to detect and sort out which ways that would be possible to execute commands as a super user on the subject code being analyzed.

By going through each instruction, it will come to conditional jumps and test both cases, when the jump is made and when it is not. So after a few iterations it would know that if a user inputs the string "s3cr3t!", it will later on come to execute commands as a super user. It would not try every possible string combination until eventually it comes to "s3cr3t!", it would be smart to see there is a comparison for that string, and see what it changes in the program flow.

Then, it would also be able to see that any user input string that has more than 8 letters would overflow the allocated space for the buf char array, thereby corrupting memory. Which in this particular case, assuming that the stack memory layout for this was that the is_admin variable would be sitting right next to the buf char array, would set is_admin to evaluate to TRUE, and then comes to execute commands as super user.

It would also be able to spot an integer overflow in that gets() function, if that would corrupt stack memory somehow that would end up changing the RETURN address from a function call. Figuring it would be a scenario for exploitation where the user inputs the shellcode and by overwriting the RETURN address it would then jump to that shellcode which would also execute commands as a super user.

So... I know I could not go into much detail on the inner workings, but overall I think I made my point. Does anyone see something wrong with that approach or thinks it would not work?

I am thinking about going for an open project on this. I would appreciate any considerations.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is such thing. Search for static analysis, control flow graph and such things. So generally, your idea is good.

However, writing a program that will find all the bugs in some program is impossible. The proof is by reduction from the Halting problem. So obviously, it is impossilbe to use your approach to find them all.

However, it might be possible to find all the bugs of some family.
For example: I can define the "bug family" of crashing within one minute when only one ASCII char is given as input. Of course you can check this (at least for deterministic programs, for probabilistic programs - a simple check will give probability that there is no bug).

So for spcific bugs your approach might work.

And last thing: notice that this approach might have high time complexity.